# multiple Field Separators in awk

Tags: regex, string, awk

i have this string

```
-foo {{0.000 0.000} {648.0 0.000} {648.0 1980.0} {0.000 1980.0} {0.000 0.000}}
```

i want to separate it to numbers and iterate over them ,thanks
tried to use Field separator without success how can i do it with awk?

Comment: You're looking for a regexp? Something like `\d+\.\d+`?

Comment: yep ,but i have understood that \d+ doesn`t work with awk

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk -F'}+|{+| ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ "[0-9]") print $i}' file.txt
```

The Field Separator `FS` (the `-F` switch) can be a character, a word, a regex or a class of characters.

You can use this too :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="}+|{+| "} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ "[0-9]")print $i}' file.txt
```

### explanations

- `foo|bar|base` is a regex where it can match any of the strings separated by the `|`
- in `}+|{+|`, we have the choice to match a literal `}` at least one : `+`, or a literal `{` at least one : `+`, or a space.
- you can use a class of character too to do the same : `[{} ]`, both works

Comment: thanks sputnick
can ypu please explain the '}+|{+| ' seperator

Comment: @stArdustͲ I want to get either a colon or spaces as the separator, however, it seems awk -F ':| ' doesn't work. Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the answer: awk -F ':[ \t]*|[ \t]+'. Thanks to this link: http://softpanorama.org/Tools/Awk/awk_regular_expressions.shtml

Answer (score 1):

One way with awk :

```
awk -F'[{} ]' '{ for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) if( $i ~ /[0-9.]+/ ) print $i }' file
```

In the line above, we went through those numbers, but I didn't do anything special, just printed them. You could add your logic to that part.

Output:

```
0.000
0.000
648.0
0.000
648.0
1980.0
0.000
1980.0
0.000
0.000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display each number on a new line then simply use `grep`:

```
$ egrep -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file
0.000
0.000
648.0
0.000
648.0
1980.0
0.000
1980.0
0.000
0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I am being very simple-minded in my offering. In my experience, the regex examples for the field separator are the most valuable to learn, especially if you have to deal with XML, etc. But in this case, we must remember that UNIX gives you *many* alternatives when confronted with characters that are irrelevant. A simple fix is to just remove the unwanted characters. There are various ways, but I would use `tr -d '{}'` like so:

```
tr -d '{}' file.txt | awk '{ for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) print $i }'
```

Starting the loop counter `i` at 2 is just a quick way to skip the first argument (`-foo`)